# YouTube video_id from Firefox bookmark.html source code [almost there]

Tags: python, youtube, gdata

bookmarks.html looks like this:

```
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg81zi0pheg" ADD_DATE="1320876124" LAST_MODIFIED="1320878745" ICON_URI="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/favicon-vflZlzSbU.ico" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABEElEQVQ4jaWSPU7DQBCF3wGo7DZp4qtEQqJJlSu4jLgBNS0dRDR0QARSumyPRJogkIJiWiToYhrSEPJR7Hptx/kDRhrNm93nb3ZXFsD4psPRwR4AzbjHxd0ru4a8kEgvbf1NePfzbQdJfro52UcS8fHQDyjWCuDz7QpJTOYLZk5nH0zmi/8Dzg/DEqgCmL1fW/PXNwADf4V7AMbuis24txrw1xBJAlHgMizoLdkI4CVBREEZWTKGK9bKqa3G3QDO2G7Z2ljqAYyxPmPgI4XHpw2A7ES+d/unZzlwM2BNnwEKb1QFGJNPabdg9GB1v2993W71BNOamNZEWpfXy5nW8/3U9UQBkqTyy677F6rrkvQDptjzJ/PSbekAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg81zi0pheg</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP9VjGmmhfo" ADD_DATE="1320876156" LAST_MODIFIED="1320878756" ICON_URI="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/favicon-vflZlzSbU.ico" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABEElEQVQ4jaWSPU7DQBCF3wGo7DZp4qtEQqJJlSu4jLgBNS0dRDR0QARSumyPRJogkIJiWiToYhrSEPJR7Hptx/kDRhrNm93nb3ZXFsD4psPRwR4AzbjHxd0ru4a8kEgvbf1NePfzbQdJfro52UcS8fHQDyjWCuDz7QpJTOYLZk5nH0zmi/8Dzg/DEqgCmL1fW/PXNwADf4V7AMbuis24txrw1xBJAlHgMizoLdkI4CVBREEZWTKGK9bKqa3G3QDO2G7Z2ljqAYyxPmPgI4XHpw2A7ES+d/unZzlwM2BNnwEKb1QFGJNPabdg9GB1v2993W71BNOamNZEWpfXy5nW8/3U9UQBkqTyy677F6rrkvQDptjzJ/PSbekAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP9VjGmmhfo</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTA1u6D1fyE" ADD_DATE="1320876163" LAST_MODIFIED="1320878762" ICON_URI="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/favicon-vflZlzSbU.ico" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABEElEQVQ4jaWSPU7DQBCF3wGo7DZp4qtEQqJJlSu4jLgBNS0dRDR0QARSumyPRJogkIJiWiToYhrSEPJR7Hptx/kDRhrNm93nb3ZXFsD4psPRwR4AzbjHxd0ru4a8kEgvbf1NePfzbQdJfro52UcS8fHQDyjWCuDz7QpJTOYLZk5nH0zmi/8Dzg/DEqgCmL1fW/PXNwADf4V7AMbuis24txrw1xBJAlHgMizoLdkI4CVBREEZWTKGK9bKqa3G3QDO2G7Z2ljqAYyxPmPgI4XHpw2A7ES+d/unZzlwM2BNnwEKb1QFGJNPabdg9GB1v2993W71BNOamNZEWpfXy5nW8/3U9UQBkqTyy677F6rrkvQDptjzJ/PSbekAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTA1u6D1fyE</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v8HvQf4fgE" ADD_DATE="1320876186" LAST_MODIFIED="1320878767" ICON_URI="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/favicon-vflZlzSbU.ico" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABEElEQVQ4jaWSPU7DQBCF3wGo7DZp4qtEQqJJlSu4jLgBNS0dRDR0QARSumyPRJogkIJiWiToYhrSEPJR7Hptx/kDRhrNm93nb3ZXFsD4psPRwR4AzbjHxd0ru4a8kEgvbf1NePfzbQdJfro52UcS8fHQDyjWCuDz7QpJTOYLZk5nH0zmi/8Dzg/DEqgCmL1fW/PXNwADf4V7AMbuis24txrw1xBJAlHgMizoLdkI4CVBREEZWTKGK9bKqa3G3QDO2G7Z2ljqAYyxPmPgI4XHpw2A7ES+d/unZzlwM2BNnwEKb1QFGJNPabdg9GB1v2993W71BNOamNZEWpfXy5nW8/3U9UQBkqTyy677F6rrkvQDptjzJ/PSbekAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v8HvQf4fgE</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9zG20wQQ1U" ADD_DATE="1320876195" LAST_MODIFIED="1320878773" ICON_URI="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/favicon-vflZlzSbU.ico" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABEElEQVQ4jaWSPU7DQBCF3wGo7DZp4qtEQqJJlSu4jLgBNS0dRDR0QARSumyPRJogkIJiWiToYhrSEPJR7Hptx/kDRhrNm93nb3ZXFsD4psPRwR4AzbjHxd0ru4a8kEgvbf1NePfzbQdJfro52UcS8fHQDyjWCuDz7QpJTOYLZk5nH0zmi/8Dzg/DEqgCmL1fW/PXNwADf4V7AMbuis24txrw1xBJAlHgMizoLdkI4CVBREEZWTKGK9bKqa3G3QDO2G7Z2ljqAYyxPmPgI4XHpw2A7ES+d/unZzlwM2BNnwEKb1QFGJNPabdg9GB1v2993W71BNOamNZEWpfXy5nW8/3U9UQBkqTyy677F6rrkvQDptjzJ/PSbekAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9zG20wQQ1U</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khL4s2bvn-8" ADD_DATE="1320876203" LAST_MODIFIED="1320878782" ICON_URI="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/favicon-vflZlzSbU.ico" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABEElEQVQ4jaWSPU7DQBCF3wGo7DZp4qtEQqJJlSu4jLgBNS0dRDR0QARSumyPRJogkIJiWiToYhrSEPJR7Hptx/kDRhrNm93nb3ZXFsD4psPRwR4AzbjHxd0ru4a8kEgvbf1NePfzbQdJfro52UcS8fHQDyjWCuDz7QpJTOYLZk5nH0zmi/8Dzg/DEqgCmL1fW/PXNwADf4V7AMbuis24txrw1xBJAlHgMizoLdkI4CVBREEZWTKGK9bKqa3G3QDO2G7Z2ljqAYyxPmPgI4XHpw2A7ES+d/unZzlwM2BNnwEKb1QFGJNPabdg9GB1v2993W71BNOamNZEWpfXy5nW8/3U9UQBkqTyy677F6rrkvQDptjzJ/PSbekAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khL4s2bvn-8</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTndQ7bYV0A" ADD_DATE="1320876271" LAST_MODIFIED="1320876271">Paramore - Walmart Soundcheck 6-For a pessimist(HQ)</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTT2MqgWRRc" ADD_DATE="1320876284" LAST_MODIFIED="1320876284">Paramore - Walmart Soundcheck 5-Pressure(HQ)</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2ZYQngwSUw" ADD_DATE="1320876291" LAST_MODIFIED="1320876291">Paramore - Wal-Mart Soundcheck Interview</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RZwvg7unrU" ADD_DATE="1320878207" LAST_MODIFIED="1320878207">Paramore - 08 - Interview [ Wal-Mart Soundcheck ]</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vz3qOYWwm10" ADD_DATE="1320878295" LAST_MODIFIED="1320878295">Paramore - 04 - That&#39;s What You Get [ Wal-Mart Soundcheck ]</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yarv52QX_Yw" ADD_DATE="1320878301" LAST_MODIFIED="1320878301">Paramore - 05 - Pressure [ Wal-Mart Soundcheck ]</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRREY1H3GCI" ADD_DATE="1320878317" LAST_MODIFIED="1320878317">Paramore - Walmart Promo</A>
```

It's a standard bookmarks export file from Firefox.

I feed it into bookmarks.py which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import BeautifulSoup as bs
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 

url_list = sys.argv[1]
urls = [tag['href'] for tag in 
BeautifulSoup(open(url_list)).findAll('a')] 

print urls
```

This returns a much more clean list of urls:

```
[u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg81zi0pheg', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP9VjGmmhfo', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTA1u6D1fyE', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v8HvQf4fgE', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9zG20wQQ1U', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khL4s2bvn-8', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTndQ7bYV0A', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTT2MqgWRRc', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2ZYQngwSUw', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RZwvg7unrU', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vz3qOYWwm10', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yarv52QX_Yw', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRREY1H3GCI']
```

my next step is to get each of the youtube urls into video_info.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urlparse
import sys
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service
import re
import urlparse
import urllib2

youtube_url = sys.argv[1]
url_data = urlparse.urlparse(youtube_url)
query = urlparse.parse_qs(url_data.query)
youtube_id = query["v"][0]

print youtube_id

yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
yt_service.developer_key = 'AI39si4yOmI0GEhSTXH0nkiVDf6tQjCkqoys5BBYLKEr-PQxWJ0IlwnUJAcdxpocGLBBCapdYeMLIsB7KVC_OA8gYK0VKV726g'

entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id=youtube_id)

print 'Video title: %s' % entry.media.title.text
print 'Video view count: %s' % entry.statistics.view_count
```

when this url "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXrgwC1rsw4" the output looks like this:

```
aXrgwC1rsw4
Video title: OneRepublic   Good Life  Live Walmart Soundcheck
Video view count: 202
```

**How do I feed the list of urls from bookmarks.py into video_info.py?**

*extra points for output to csv format and
extra extra points of checking of duplicates in bookmarks.html before passing data to video_info.py*

Thanks for all your help guys. Because of Stackoverflow I've gotten this far.

David

#

So combined I now have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urlparse
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service
import re
import urlparse
import urllib2
import sys
import BeautifulSoup as bs
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 

yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
yt_service.developer_key = 'AI39si4yOmI0GEhSTXH0nkiVDf6tQjCkqoys5BBYLKEr-PQxWJ0IlwnUJAcdxpocGLBBCapdYeMLIsB7KVC_OA8gYK0VKV726g'

url_list = sys.argv[1]
urls = [tag['href'] for tag in 
BeautifulSoup(open(url_list)).findAll('a')] 

print urls

youtube_url = urls
url_data = urlparse.urlparse(youtube_url)
query = urlparse.parse_qs(url_data.query)
youtube_id = query["v"][0]

#list(set(my_list))

entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id=youtube_id)

myyoutubes = []
myyoutubes.append(", ".join([youtube_id, entry.media.title.text,entry.statistics.view_count]))
print "\n".join(myyoutubes)
```

**How do I pass the list of urls to the youtube_url variable?**
*they need to be cleaned up further and passed one at a time I believe*

I've got it down to this now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urlparse
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service
import re
import urlparse
import urllib2
import sys
import BeautifulSoup as bs
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 

yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
yt_service.developer_key = 'AI39si4yOmI0GEhSTXH0nkiVDf6tQjCkqoys5BBYLKEr-PQxWJ0IlwnUJAcdxpocGLBBCapdYeMLIsB7KVC_OA8gYK0VKV726g'

url_list = sys.argv[1]
urls = [tag['href'] for tag in 
    BeautifulSoup(open(url_list)).findAll('a')] 

for url in urls:
    youtube_url = url

url_data = urlparse.urlparse(youtube_url)
query = urlparse.parse_qs(url_data.query)
youtube_id = query["v"][0]

#list(set(my_list))

entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id=youtube_id)

myyoutubes = []
myyoutubes.append(", ".join([youtube_id, entry.media.title.text,entry.statistics.view_count]))
print "\n".join(myyoutubes)
```

I can pass bookmarks.html to combined.py but it only returns the first line.

**How to I loop through each line of youtube_url?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide a string to `BeautifulSoup`:

```
# parse bookmarks.html
with open(sys.argv[1]) as bookmark_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(bookmark_file.read())

# extract youtube video urls
video_url_regex = re.compile('http://www.youtube.com/watch')
urls = [link['href'] for link in soup('a', href=video_url_regex)]
```

Separate a very fast url parsing from a much longer downloading of the stats:

```
# extract video ids from the urls
ids = [] # you could use `set()` and `ids.add()` to avoid duplicates
for video_url in urls:
    url = urlparse.urlparse(video_url)
    video_id = urlparse.parse_qs(url.query).get('v')
    if not video_id: continue # no video_id in the url
    ids.append(video_id[0])
```

You don't need to authenticate for readonly requests:

```
# get some statistics for the videos
yt_service = YouTubeService()
yt_service.ssl = True #NOTE: it works for readonly requests
yt_service.debug = True # show requests
```

Save some statistics to a csv file provided on the command-line. Don't stop if some video causes an error:

```
writer = csv.writer(open(sys.argv[2], 'wb')) # save to cvs file
for video_id in ids:
    try:
        entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id=video_id)
    except Exception, e:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Failed to retrieve entry video_id=%s: %s" %(
            video_id, e)
    else:
        title = entry.media.title.text
        print "Title:", title
        view_count = entry.statistics.view_count
        print "View count:", view_count
        writer.writerow((video_id, title, view_count)) # write it
```

Here's [a full script](https://www.stypi.com/9cace2om), press playback to watch how it was written.

#### Output

```
$ python download-video-stats.py neudorfer.html out.csv
send: u'GET https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Gg81zi0pheg HTTP/1.1\r\nAcc
ept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: gdata.youtube.com\r\nContent-Type: application/ato
m+xml\r\nUser-Agent: None GData-Python/2.0.15\r\n\r\n'                           
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: X-GData-User-Country: RU
header: Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
header: Expires: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 19:31:23 GMT
header: Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 19:31:23 GMT
header: Cache-Control: private, max-age=300, no-transform
header: Vary: *
header: GData-Version: 1.0
header: Last-Modified: Wed, 02 Nov 2011 08:58:11 GMT
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: Server: GSE
Title: Paramore - Let The Flames Begin [Wal-Mart Soundcheck]
View count: 27807
```

#### out.csv

```
Gg81zi0pheg,Paramore - Let The Flames Begin [Wal-Mart Soundcheck],27807
pP9VjGmmhfo,Paramore: Wal-Mart Soundcheck,1363078
yTA1u6D1fyE,Paramore-Walmart Soundcheck 7-CrushCrushCrush(HQ),843
4v8HvQf4fgE,Paramore-Walmart Soundcheck 4-That's What You Get(HQ),1429
e9zG20wQQ1U,Paramore-Walmart Soundcheck 8-Interview(HQ),1306
khL4s2bvn-8,Paramore-Walmart Soundcheck 3-Emergency(HQ),796
XTndQ7bYV0A,Paramore-Walmart Soundcheck 6-For a pessimist(HQ),599
xTT2MqgWRRc,Paramore-Walmart Soundcheck 5-Pressure(HQ),963
J2ZYQngwSUw,Paramore - Wal-Mart Soundcheck Interview,10261
9RZwvg7unrU,Paramore - 08 - Interview [Wal-Mart Soundcheck],1674
vz3qOYWwm10,Paramore - 04 - That's What You Get [Wal-Mart Soundcheck],1268
yarv52QX_Yw,Paramore - 05 - Pressure [Wal-Mart Soundcheck],1296
LRREY1H3GCI,Paramore - Walmart Promo,523
```

Comment: @David Neudorfer: Don't copy-paste mindlessly. Comments that make sense in the context of the question for one-off script are not appropriate as a part of a project source. Try to read the code and understand what every line does e.g., [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#dir) is usually used at interactive prompt or for a quick debugging; it should not be in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Sebastian. I'll see what I can do to correct that.

Comment: Sebastian, do you do for hire work? I can't find a website or email on your profile.

Comment: @David Neudorfer: the code is under [CC BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license, like everything else on the site. I've updated the profile.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just combine the two files? Also, you may want to break it up into methods to make it easier to understand later.

Also, for csv you're going to want to accumulate your data.  So, maybe have a list and each time through append a csv line of youtube info:

```
myyoutubes = []
...
myyoutubes.append(", ".join([youtubeid, entry.media.title.text,entry.statistics.view_count]))
...
"\n".join(myyoutubes)
```

For duplicates, I normally do this: 
     list(set(my_list))
Sets only have unique elements.

Comment: oneporter, what I have so far took me about 12 hours. Any help beyond what you've already done would be amazing. (obviously, thank you for pointing me in the right direction) :)

Comment: David, I mean you can combine bookmarks.py and video_info.py.  Use code from bookmarks.py to grab all the urls.  Then loop over the urls with the body of the loop being video_info.py.  So, for youtubeurl in urls: <stuff from video_info.py>

Comment: Before I can pass the cleaned urls from bookmarks.py to video_info.py they need to be cleaned up slightly more. I've asked that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084935/clean-url-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: I have no idea how to loop :(

Comment: No worries.. You're shown how to loop in the link you provided.  Check this out http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: Got it. Loops are working and I can feed bookmarks.html into my combined.py script but it only returns the first line. Any help on making it loop for each line?