# Clean URL with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My script

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 
url_list = sys.argv[1]
urls = [tag['href'] for tag in 
    BeautifulSoup(open(url_list)).findAll('a')]
```

returns

```
[u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg81zi0pheg', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP9VjGmmhfo', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTA1u6D1fyE', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v8HvQf4fgE', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9zG20wQQ1U', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khL4s2bvn-8', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTndQ7bYV0A', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTT2MqgWRRc', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2ZYQngwSUw', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RZwvg7unrU', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vz3qOYWwm10', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yarv52QX_Yw', u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRREY1H3GCI']
```

I would like it to return this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg81zi0pheg
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP9VjGmmhfo
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTA1u6D1fyE
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v8HvQf4fgE
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9zG20wQQ1U
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khL4s2bvn-8
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTndQ7bYV0A
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTT2MqgWRRc
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2ZYQngwSUw
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RZwvg7unrU
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vz3qOYWwm10
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yarv52QX_Yw
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRREY1H3GCI
```

I am having a really hard time wrapping my head around BeautifulSoup. Anything would help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hey David, I just read your other question where you mentioned that you have no idea how to loop. I think you'll find that you have a lot easier time writing python after a brief introduction to the language. Based on what you already seem to understand, I would suggest working through parts 6, 7, 8 and 9 of A Byte of Python. http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Python_en:Table_of_Contents Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But this is completely basic Python. You're getting a list, and you want to output it one URL per line.

```
for url in urls:
    print url
```

Answer (score 2):

It pretty much is returning that. What you see is simply a list of url strings, encoded as [unicode strings](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) (that's why there's a `u` in front of them).

If you simply want to print these urls nicely, Python has a module for pretty printing that can be used as follows:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(my_list_of_urls)
```

However, this won't print them line by line. To do that you'll need to use:

```
for url in my_list_of_urls:
    print url
```

Edit:

I just tried the pretty print module on a list of unicode strings, and I don't think it actually does anything different with the 'u' in front of the strings. I'm leaving it in because it can do wonders with representing long data structures.

Comment: it does give me one per line but it doesn't remove the u' in the before and the `, after

Comment: Like I said, there is a `u` there because the string is encoded as unicode (rather than ascii). When working with content from the web, having your strings as unicode is a Good Thing. It doesn't really change much about how you can use them, but dramatically increases the range of characters you can represent. If you have a reason why unicode isn't working for you, edit your question to include that information. Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode