# YouTube Average Rating in Python

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

How can I call the gd:rating XML file using the Python YouTube GData API?

I have the YouTube video_id as a variable and I know it's possible to return this:

```
<gd:rating average='4.553648' max='5' min='1' numRaters='233' rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall'/>
```

I just can't figure out how to do it in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083268/youtube-video-id-from-firefox-bookmark-html-source-code-almost-there) you've already demonstrated the code that retrieves an entry given a `video_id`.

Run `python`:

```
>>> from gdata.youtube.service import YouTubeService
>>> yt = YouTubeService()
>>> entry = yt.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id='pP9VjGmmhfo')
>>> entry.rating
<gdata.youtube.Rating object at 0x2722cd0>
>>> print entry.rating
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:rating average="4.4662576" max="5" min="1" numRaters="652" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" />
>>> entry.rating.average
'4.4662576'
>>> entry.rating.numRaters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Rating' object has no attribute 'numRaters'
>>> dir(entry.rating)
['FindExtensions', 'ToString', '_AddMembersToElementTree', '_BecomeChildElement', '_ConvertElementAttributeToMember', '_ConvertElementTreeToMember', '_HarvestElementTree', '_ToElementTree', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_attributes', '_children', '_namespace', '_tag', 'average', 'extension_attributes', 'extension_elements', 'max', 'min', 'num_raters', 'text']
>>> entry.rating.num_raters
'652'
```

Comment: Thank you J.F. Now it's just figuring out where to place

`dir(entry.rating)`

https://www.stypi.com/davidneudorfer/youtube.py

Comment: @David Neudorfer: If you don't know what "Run `python`" means then do at least `Exercise 0: The Setup` from the book [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/).

Comment: no no I have the above script working in:
https://www.stypi.com/davidneudorfer/watch_likes_dislikes.py
but I can't figure out how to merge it with my main script:
https://www.stypi.com/davidneudorfer/youtube.py

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: How could I modify your script to handle a video_id that has no attribute 'average'? for example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCMkODUS3Mk

Comment: @David Neudorfer: add `if entry.rating is None: # skip it..`